# Is it a bad idea to just create a Text component that always translated its contents with react-i18next?

Tags: react-native, react-i18next

In the process of translating a smallish RN app (50% done), I noticed that most of the strings on *React Native* are displayed via `Text` components. So I wrote the following class and used it instead of *React Native's* `Text`:

```
import {Text as RNText} from 'react-native';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export default ({children, style}) => {
  const {t} = useTranslation();
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    const translated = children.map((el) => t(el));
    return <RNText style={style}>{translated}</RNText>;
  }

  const translated = t(children);
  return <RNText style={style}>{translated}</RNText>;
};
```

This worked so well and was so pragmatic in my case that I wondered if its a bad idea - otherwise I feel like it would have been cited in the documentation as a good way to use `react-i18next`.

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this works well for you, good job! you should definitely keep using the component.

This usage is probably not documented in `react-i18next` for a variety of reason:

1. It's good for a library to leave the users complete freedom over its usages. I would prefer the mainteners of `react-i18next` to focus on improving the translation aspect than using resource mainiting those kind of components;
2. It's trivial for users to write such a component themselves supporting their specific use cases, as you did;
3. Such a compoment does not handle all edge cases, so in your codebase there are probably some situations where you don't use the component but you still use `Text` in the good old way. Think about a string with some variables you need to pass to:

```js
<Text>{t('key', { value: this.state.value })}</Text>
```

Many developer probably prefer to keep the little additional verbosity to repeat `t()` each time, in exchange of a better standard behaviour that suits all edge cases cases.